# Reload the PowerShell module every time the script is executing

Tags: powershell, module, reload

I have a class in the PowerShell module file. (`A.psm1`)

```
class A  {

    [void] printString() {
        write-host 111
    }

}
```

And I also have a simple script that uses that class.

```
Using module C:\temp\A.psm1

$a = [A]::new()
$a.printString()  # prints 111
```

But if I change the method from the class, for example, as shown here (replace `111` on `222`)

```
[void] printString() {
     write-host 222
}
```

and if I relaunch my script it will still print `111`. Only if I restart the PowerShell console it will print the new value.
If I worked only in the console, I could use the `Import-Module ... -Force` command. But it doesn't work in the script.

So is there a way to reload the PowerShell module every time the script is launched without restarting the console itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This unfortunate behavior is a [well-known issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654), and [as mklement0 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028622/712649) *no real **good** solution* exist at the moment.

The underlying cause is a bit convoluted (part of the reason the behavior persists after 5+ years), but it's basically a 3-way conflict between:

- Module lifecycle management in PowerShell (modules are *supposed* to be reloadable)
- Type definition lifecycle management in .NET (a type can never be "un-defined" for the lifetime of the process*)
- The way `using module` provides parse-time resolution of custom types - its not a particularly *mature* feature to put it plainly

---

Although no good solution exists, the VSCode PowerShell extension has a configuration option [allowing you to run debug sessions in a temporary shell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654#issuecomment-439557319), making it a non-issue:

[image]

```
{
  "powershell.debugging.createTemporaryIntegratedConsole": true
}
```

Once set, you can use the following workflow for testing/debugging:

1. Open the script in the editor
2. Run it via the debugger (`Shift+Ctrl+D` -> `Run and Debug`)
3. Observe `printString()` prints `111`
4. Make changes to the module file, save it
5. Run the script via the debugger again
6. Observe `printString()` now prints the new value

Comment: Thanks! The workaround in VS Code suits my needs!

Comment: @АртурГудиев Great to hear, you're welcome! FWIW this is also how I develop modules with classes :-)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, **there's no good solution**, unfortunately (as of PowerShell 7.2): The `using module` statement - which is the prerequisite for also loading `class`es from a module - has no equivalent to the [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)'s `-Force` switch for forcing *reloading* of a module.

**Workaround**:

```
# (Force-re)load the module and get a reference to the module.
# This does NOT give you access to the classes defined in the module.
$module = Import-Module C:\temp\A.psm1 -PassThru -Force

# Use the module reference to execute code *in the module's* context,
# where the class *is* defined, so you can obtain a reference to the
# [A] class (type) this way:
$classA = & $module { [A] }

$classA::new().printString()
```

- As you can see, this **requires *modifying the source code***.
- **If you're using Visual Studio Code with the PowerShell extension, you can avoid this**, as shown in [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028718/45375).