# I created a custom powershell .psm1 module but it won't update after an edit

Tags: powershell, module

I created a custom powershell module in the
`C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PennoniAppManagement` directory. Whenever I make changes to a function in the module, then import the module into a script, the updated code won't take effect. Any solutions?

Comment: Run `Remove-Module PennoniAppManagement -Force` before re-importing

Comment: This is exactly what I needed thank you.

Comment: Did `Import-Module mymodule -Force` not work for you?

Comment: @Abraham Zinala ```Import-Module mymodule -Force``` did not work for me

Comment: That's odd, that's really why the parameter is there. Glad Mathias solution worked for you tho!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you remove the already-loaded version of the module from the session before re-importing it:

```
Remove-Module PennoniAppManagement -Force
Import-Module PennoniAppManagement
```

Comment: @mklement0 I've run into many oddities with scoped resolution of custom types/classes when re-importing during module development, so `rmo -force;ipmo` has been a force of habit since ~5.1. I don't know if that's what OP is experiencing too though...

Comment: @mklement0 Nice, I'll try and see if I can reproduce the class visibility issue and get back to you (the problem, as I recall: scoped type resolver isn't/wasn't nuked unless `Remove-Module -Force` was called, so changes to class definitions wouldn't be reflected on re-import because cached entries of old implementations "linger" in the resolver).

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, that's my recollection - so you'd make a structural change to a class definition, update your tests/functions, then `Import-Module -Force` and find that everything fails because `[myCustomType]` still resolves to the previous version (but commands have been updated correctly)

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. I've added this information to my answer; I've also added a simple test case, which, however, does _not_ exhibit this problem, neither in WinPS nor in PS Core. Of course, there still could be problems, in older WinPS versions and/or in more complex scenarios. Please let us know if you can think of a reproducible case. (And the OP's own feedback suggests that they indeed ran into a problem).

Answer (score 5):

- *Normally*, [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)**`-Force`** - by itself - is enough to *force* reloading of an updated module into the current session.

  - `Import-Module -Force` *implicitly* performs `Remove-Module` before reloading the module (if the module isn't currently loaded, `-Force` just loads the module normally).
  - Also note that **force-reloading a module is *not* an option if you're loading it via a `using module` statement** (at least as of PowerShell 7.1.2). Notably the `using module` method of importing is required if a module exports custom `class` definitions that the caller should see - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028622/45375) for details.
- [Mathias' *two-step* approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610484/45375) - `Remove-Module -Force`, followed by `Import-Module` - is apparently needed in *some* cases, and seems to be required in yours.

  - It would be good to understand *when* the two-step approach is needed. Mathias thinks it is related to *cached versions of custom `class` definitions (used module-internally) lingering* instead of getting reloaded and redefined when `Import-Module -Force` is called. That is, while the module overall may get reloaded, it may be operating on *stale* `class`es. At least in the simple scenario below I was *not* able to reproduce this problem, neither in Windows PowerShell 5.1, nor in PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1, but there may be scenarios where the problem does surface.
  - The [`Remove-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module) documentation describes the `-Force` parameter solely as relating to the - rarely used - [`.AccessMode` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo.AccessMode) available on a *loaded* module's module-information object (you can inspect it with `(`[`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) `...).AccessMode`). The default value is `ReadWrite`, which allows unloading (removal) of the module anytime. If the property value is `ReadOnly`, `Remove-Module -Force` is needed to unload; if it is `Constant`, the module cannot be removed from the session at all, once loaded - at least not *with `Remove-Module`*.

    - Notably, the *implicit* unloading that happens with `Import-Module -Force` is *not* subject to these restrictions and implicitly unloads a module even if its `.AccessMode` is `Constant` (as of PowerShell 7.1.2; I am unclear on whether that is by design).

---

**Test code** involving **reloading a module with a modified `class` definition**, to see if `Import-Module -Force` is enough:

```sh
# Create a template for the content of a sample script module.
# Note: The doubled { and } are needed for use of the string with
#       with the -f operator later.
$moduleContent = @'
class MyClass {{
  [string] $Foo{0}
}}

function Get-Foo {{
  # Print the property names of custom class [MyClass]
  [MyClass]::new().psobject.Properties.Name
}}
'@

# Create the module with property name .Foo1 in the [MyClass] class.
$moduleContent -f 1  > .\Foo.psm1

# Import the module and call Get-Foo to echo the property name.
Import-Module .\Foo.psm1; Get-Foo

# Now update the module on disk by changing the property name
# to .Foo2
$moduleContent -f 2  > .\Foo.psm1

# Force-import (reload) the module and 
# see if the property name changed.
Import-Module -Force .\Foo.psm1; Get-Foo

# Clean up.
Remove-Item .\Foo.psm1
```

In both *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest and last version is v5.1) and *PowerShell (Core) 7.2.1* (current as of this writing), the above yields, as expected:

```sh
Foo1  # Original import.
Foo2  # After modifying the class and force-reloading
```